# Глобальная (в рамках приложения) обработка нажатий клавиш клавиатуры

Tags: qt, qt5

Есть приложение на Qt.
В нем множество диалогов.
Есть необходимость сделать вызов по нажатии какой либо кнопки, но, хотелось бы, сделать это глобально - один обработчик для всех форм/диалогов
Что  то ничего путного на мозг не приходит.

Может кто подскажет как это все организовать? Буду очень благода :-)

Comment: может быть сделать общий базовый класс из `QDialog` и там в конструкторе делать `installEventFilter()`

Comment: Под какой ОС? Если под Линукс - есть проект kscreenlocker
 https://github.com/KDE/kscreenlocker - можно в нем поковыряться.

Comment: все это будет крутиться под OS  Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил так:

1. сделал класс, методу которого в диалогах передается код нажатой клавиши
2. Передал ссылку на объект этого класса в конструктор всех диалогов
3. в диалогах перекрыл keyPressEvent  и в нем вызываю метод объекта

вот так

может и немного коряво, но работает :-)

Answer (score 1):

Еще есть такой опасный анти паттерн Singelton, его не рекомендуют из за сложностей с тестированием и при многопоточном программировании. Но если совсем немножко, то можно, он классный.

> #include 
> #include
>
> class Singleton : public QObject
> {
> Q_OBJECT
>
> public:
> static QSharedPointer create();
>
> private:
> explicit Singleton(QObject *parent = nullptr);
> };
>
> // singleton.cpp
> #include "singleton.h"
>
> Singleton::Singleton(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
> {
> // Конструктор
> }
>
> QSharedPointer Singleton::getInstance()
> {
> static QSharedPointer p = QSharedPointer::create();
> return p;
> }